# Product of vector transpose and matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix and $\boldsymbol{v}$ be a $n$-dimensional vector and $\boldsymbol{u}$ be a $m$-dimensional vector. I have difficulty understanding $\boldsymbol{u}\cdot (A\boldsymbol{v})=\boldsymbol{u}^TA\boldsymbol{v}$, especially $\boldsymbol{u}^TA$. Based on my understanding $A\boldsymbol{v}$ returns a $m$-dimensional vector. I am unsure what kind object is $\boldsymbol{u}^TA$. I suspect it must be a $n$-dimensional vector, right? How the multiplication is defined in in $\boldsymbol{u}^TA$?

Comment: $u$ is a column vector and its transpose is a row vector. In terms of dimensions $u^T$ is $1 \times m$ and $Av$ is $m \times 1$. Their product is a scalar. The product $u^TA$ would be a $1 \times n$ vector (i.e. a row vector).

Comment: @CBBAM I know what kind object is $\boldsymbol{u}^TA\boldsymbol{v}$. One way to evaluate it is to evaluate $A\boldsymbol{v}$ first, then multiply it at left by $\boldsymbol{u}^T$. I am interested in evaluating $\boldsymbol{u}^TA$ first then multiplying it at right by $\boldsymbol{v}$ but I don't understand what kind object is $\boldsymbol{u}^TA$.

Comment: $u^TA$ is an $n$-dimensional row vector.